# Show view in bootstrap modal not loading data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I trying to load a bootstrap modal from a link_to tag with a show view, from my index view, but the actual data is not being loaded.

controller:

```
def index
    # to avoid NoMethodError on index.html.erb
    @model = Model.new
end

def show
    @model = Model.find(params[:id])
    logger.debug @model.id # Prints the correct id, so I know the data is loaded from ActiveRecord
end
```

index.htmnl.erb

```
<%= link_to show_path(m), remote: true, data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#editModal"} do %>
  Edit
<% end %>

<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel"><%= @model.name %></h5>
....
</div
```

When index.html.erb is loaded, if you look in the source, #modalLabel is blank, which makes sense.  But, when I click to bring up the modal, it stays blank.  @model is not being refreshed from the show view in my controller.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the part where you use `js` to insert the content returned from the `remote` call to the server into the DOM (before you show the modal)?

Comment: Nonexistent? I’m still learning rails.

Comment: Right. Non-existent. And so nothing is happening on the front end - which is pretty much what you would expect given non-existent code.

Comment: Well, thank you for your response. As as I said, I’m learning rails now. I assumed that the variable on the view would update after it got updated in the controller, but obviously that is not the case. Can you help me understand how to fix my issue? Thank you.

Comment: My first suggestion is that you carefully study [the guide on Working with JavaScript](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html). There are some examples there of how to insert information returned from the server into the DOM (web page). You will also want to pay attention to the [section on Turbolinks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks) in case you are using Turbolinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `remote: true` on the `link_to` helper causes it to override the default event and fire an asynchronous request when clicked. The event is routed to your controller, but as a Javascript request.

The default convention (i.e., unless you override it) for HTML requests is for Rails to find a corresponding `.html.erb` view to render (like with your index view). When you render your index, it renders the HTML but at that stage the label is of course empty.

Javascript requests work similarly, except the convention is to look for a corresponding `js.erb` file. In your case, the request goes to your controller's `#show` method, which loads your model and looks for (among other possibilities) `model/show.js.erb`. Because you don't have one, you will likely see something like the following in your logs:

```
No template found for ArticlesController#show, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 2893)
```

So, you need to add some Javascript to update your page in `show.js.erb`. In your case something like:

```js
document.getElementById('modalLabel').textContent = "<%= @model.name %>";
```

Comment: Thank you for that wonderful explanation!  It completely solved my issue.